# Question on integration/differentiation of function series

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

Let be $S_n:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $(S_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a function series that converges for at least one point $c\in[a,b]$. Further, we assume that that the function series of $(S_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ derivatives, $(S'_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly.

Then we know that $(S_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ also converges uniformly, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S'_n$ is differentiable and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S'_n= (\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n)'$.

(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability)

---

Now let's assume we want to find a closed form of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n$ but the partial sums $S_n$ are somewhat complicated and it is hard to figure out how $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n$ looks like. However, we know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S'_n$ attains a simple form which allows us to easily find the antiderivative of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S'_n$.

---

My question is, though we are able to find the antiderivative of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S'_n$ it's not unique, so how do I know which of those antiderivatives is my desired expression for $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n$? Or am I mistaken and this strategy is not applicable in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An antiderivative of $\lim S_n'$ isn't unique but the limit of $(S_n)$ is because for some $c \in [a,b]$ the series of function converges at point $c$. Here, $\lim S_n$ is the antiderivative of $\lim S_n'$ taking the value $\lim S_n(c)$ at $c$ :
$$ (\lim S_n) (x) = \lim (S_n(c)) + \int_c^x (\lim S_n')(t)dt. $$
Also, denoting
$$ S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n f_k $$
this last formula becomes clearer :
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty} f_n(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty} f_n(c) + \int_c^x \sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty} f_n'(t)dt$$
where one can swap the series and the integral. This strategy is very useful when dealing with a series of the kind you described : the series of the derivatives is nice but the series itself isn't.

Comment: Just to check if I have understood it correctly: $G(x)=(\lim S_n)(x)+5$ is also an antiderivative of $\lim S′_n$ but $G(c)\neq \lim S_n(c)$. So the fact that we have a "known" point of our antiderivative delivers us a "unique" antiderivative, right?

Comment: Yes you got the idea. Also note that your example is a bit weird because in the theorem you are considering, $\lim S_n$ is derived from $\lim S_n'$ so you are going kind of backward.